# Why does this injection proof not work

Tags: functions

Hello I am trying to make sense of the theorem

Suppose A is a set, the following are equivalent.

1. A is countable
2. Either $A = \emptyset$ or there is a onto function $$f: \mathbb{Z^{+}} \to A$$
3. There is an injective function $$f: A \to \mathbb{Z^+}$$

My question is, for showing that 3 implies 1, the author goes into to detail and such. But why is it not sufficient to say that since f is injective, $|A| \le |Z^{+}|$ which we know is countable and so A must be countable? Why does that not work?

Comment: I thought that, by definition, a set was countable if there exists an injection from that set to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Has the author already shown that a subset of a countable set is countable?

Comment: @Quality: What is your definition of "countable"?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument seems correct. In fact, since a subset of a countable set is countable (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Countable_Set_is_Countable) for a proof), then $f(A) \subset \mathbb{Z}^+$ is countable. But since $f$ is injective, then $A$ is in bijective correspondence with $f(A)$, showing that $A$ is indeed countable.